# In kendo grid group wise sortable rows in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm able to drag-drop individual rows in the KendoGrid.

but I want to drag and drop rows groups-wise.

Any suggestion for this? how can I achieve this?

> Kendo MVC code

```
//Model class
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public decimal Discontinued { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}

//Controller
public ActionResult KendoGridDragDrop()
{
    List<ProductViewModel> lstData = new List<ProductViewModel>()
    {
        new ProductViewModel(){Group="A",ProductName="A1",UnitPrice=10,Discontinued=1,UnitsInStock=50},
        new ProductViewModel(){Group="A",ProductName="B1",UnitPrice=20,Discontinued=2,UnitsInStock=60},
        new ProductViewModel(){Group="B",ProductName="C1",UnitPrice=30,Discontinued=3,UnitsInStock=70},
        new ProductViewModel(){Group="C",ProductName="D1",UnitPrice=40,Discontinued=4,UnitsInStock=80},
        new ProductViewModel(){Group="C",ProductName="E1",UnitPrice=50,Discontinued=5,UnitsInStock=90},
    };
    return View("KendoGridDragDrop", lstData);
}


//cshtml page
@model IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Group).Title("Group").GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>Count: @item.Count</text>);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Title("Unit Price").Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Title("Units In Stock").Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Discontinued).Width(130);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(16)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.Group))
     )
)
@(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
    .For("#Grid")
    .Filter("table > tbody > tr")
    .Cursor("move")
    .HintHandler("noHint")
    .PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
    .ContainerSelector("#Grid tbody")
    .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
)

<script>
    var noHint = $.noop;

    function placeholder(element) {
        return element.clone().addClass("k-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
    }

    function onChange(e) {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid"),
            skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
            oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
            newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
            data = grid.dataSource.data(),
            dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
    }
</script>

<style>
    .k-grid tbody tr {
        cursor: move;
    }
</style>
```

[image]